# Why is my PS4 controller showing up as "rdamicro" on my PC?

Tags: pc, ps4, controllers

Instead of showing up as wireless controller, it shows up as "rdamicro."

I plugged in my PS4 controller to my PC and I have installed ds4windows and its drivers, but my PC is detecting my controller as "rdamicro" when it's supposed to be a wireless controller when it's plugged in.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I plugged in my ps4 controller to my pc i have installed ds4windows and its drivers,but my pc is detecting my controller as rdamicro its supposed to be wireless controller when its plugged in

Comment: I haven't had a problem with that... could it be a virus?

Comment: Do you have anything else plugged in to your PC via a cable while trying to do this (other than the basic things like a keyboard/mouse)?

Answer (score 2):

I think this can happen with the Jays2Kings version of DS4Windows which isn't compatible with recent versions of Windows 10 and is no longer supported by the developer.

The project's [README](https://github.com/Jays2Kings/DS4Windows) suggests that you use a different DS4Windows fork:

> This version of DS4Windows is no longer maintained and will recieve no future updates. For a newer version and more updates, download [Ryochan7's DS4Windows](https://github.com/Ryochan7/DS4Windows)

If Windows says your Dualshock4 is currently in a "Driver error" state then you'll need to [fix that](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/ps4-controller-device-driver-error-on-pc/5896f353-66f3-4dfe-baf6-5e28a9f316ae) before it will work again.

Comment: I might be a lot within steam's ecosystem, but really, DS4Windows is a program that I think is on its last legs. Steam does the PS4 controller setup now (And even switch) and does it while being officially supported, instead of having to rely on the goodwill of a few devs that could drop the project tomorrow.

Comment: I highly recommend [ScpToolkit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scptoolkit.mirror/) over DS4Windows.  Not only does it work with Windows 10, but it has better compatibility with games (in my experience).

Answer (score 1):

It could also simply be a knock-off third party chinese controller.
Got one showing the same on my pc and opened it. Was not a genuine controller.
Hope this help.